# Do CRITICAL_SECTION Objects Get Reclaimed After Program Exit?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using a CRITICAL_SECTION object. If I do not call DeleteCriticalSection() as my program shuts down, does that leaked resource get reclaimed automatically by the OS? Or is it permanently leaked?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - all local (non-shared) transient resources are cleaned up on application termination, including CRITICAL_SECTION objects.